# How to change pathway to find React-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to import modules from React-bootstrap

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import FormGroup from 'react-bootstrap/FormGroup'
import ControlLabel from 'react-bootstrap/ControlLabel'
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl'


const marked = require("marked")

class App extends Component {

render(){
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <div>
         <FormGroup controlID="formControlTextarea">
          <ControlLabel>Markdown Input</ControlLabel>
         <FormControl componentClass="textarea" placeholder="Enter Markdown"></FormControl>
         </FormGroup>
       </div>
     </div>
    );
   }
  }

 export default App;
```

But I keep seeing this in the browser, [image]

This is my folder structure on VS Code
[image]

I've used terminal to install everything globally but still no luck. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of `react-bootstrap` you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `ControlLabel` is no longer used in react bootstrap. The current name is `FormLabel`. So you need to import it like this:

```
import FormLabel from "react-bootstrap/FormLabel";
```

And then change this:

```
<ControlLabel>Markdown Input</ControlLabel>
```

to

```
<FormLabel>Markdown Input</FormLabel>
```